# Matrix field blowing up after 6 columns

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, ee1

If I create a matrix field with 5 columns, I am fine. However, if I create one with 6 or more, I am locked out of editing custom field types. I don't see any errors. No CP errors are triggered and the data remains in the db. I cannot, however, go edit the field type to modify or remove the extra field in the matrix. I have to edit the db table and forcefully remove it from the table. After doing this, I can once again edit the fieldtype and rebuild it without the last addition. I have run into this a few times on older sites. I haven't had the need for that many matrix columns on anything in EE2 yet so I don't know if this extended to that or not. Has anyone else run into this before?

I am running EE 1.6.8 on the sites this has happened on.

Comment: What specifically are you getting when you try to edit the field? A blank white screen?

Comment: Thanks Brandon. No, not a blank white screen like many other errors, the CP looks to be normal, but nothing for a custom field. It's like it doesn't exist. It is in the DB, but doesn't show up. I didn't want to upgrade to a newer version because it's such an old build to begin with. I am rebuilding it in 2, but it is a large site and I have to maintain new stuff on it while still working on the rebuild when time allows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with Brandon on this via email and we updated everything to the newest versions. This still did not resolve the issues. I am fairly certain this issue is due to the way this old site was built and maintained. I was able to correct the issues I was having by reverting all the way back to the older FF Matrix fieldtype.

I am in the process of a complete rebuild and will be moving it all into EE2 so this should "disappear". I will set this as answered, if nothing else to remove it from the radar of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but if the Matrix field is somehow getting blown-up by the columns you're adding, it may be blowing-up the Matrix Javascript and/or EE CP Javascript, which then prevents you from editing the field.

When you try to edit fields, in what way are you "locked out"? Take a look at your browser's Javascript console, and look for errors that arise at the point where you're stuck.

Also, what version of Matrix are you using? If it's less than FF Matrix  1.3.5, you may want to upgrade to 1.3.5.

Comment: No console errors either.   ;)    I am running Matrix 2.0.11

Comment: Right, I forgot that Matrix 2 works on EE1. I don't see any mention of your issue in the [Matrix Changelog](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/changelog.html), but maybe you want to try a newer version of Matrix? Otherwise, I think you should look for input from the P&T folks.

Comment: I would try upgrading to Matrix 2.3.5 and also look at upgrading FieldFrame too.

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't want to upgrade to a newer version because of the age of the site. I updated to the version on there because Brandon said it was cool to do so.  ;)